# The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Tags: apache-2.2, php, windows-7

First of all sorry because i am new in these fields
i am going to configure Apahe2 with PHP i have downloaded both of zip setup file and configured both ini file . now when i enter `http://localhost/` it show me IIS7 page . 
but when i trying to open `http://localhost/index.php` file it show me error
"HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."apache2 path is like `c:\apache2` and php path is like `c:\php`
now i do not understand what more i have to do plz help what is wrong ?

Comment: Is there a file in the site root called `index.php`?

Comment: Sorry to hear about your problems. Unfortunately, there is quite a bit wrong with your question as it relates to being on-topic on Server Fault. Please take a look at the [faq] and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You are running two web servers on the same machine. You're expecting apache to respond to your requests, but *clearly* it is IIS that is listening on port 80 and responding.

You really have two possible solutions:

- Stop IIS and start apache on port 80
- Install PHP for IIS and use that and put your pages in the IIS document root and don't use apache at all.

Either way will work. Right now your web requests are being handled by IIS, so looking at your apache config is barking up the wrong tree.

It might be worthwhile for you to get a book or two on this kind of thing.